# How to be alerted by email when new vbulletin version is available

Tags: vbulletin

I currently have a vbulletin install and I don't log into the admin control panel very often - but I need to be alerted when a security patch or new version is available.

I cannot find this option anywhere - does anyone know where you can find it? Or if it exists?

Comment: Is there not a mailing list or news feed you can subscribe to direct from [vBulletin](http://www.vbulletin.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to newsletters in the customer area at the bottom of the page: http://members.vbulletin.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are the owner of the vBulletin license running on your site, you're automagically subscribed to the vBulletin mailing-list.